# Modifying object properties with a method

Tags: javascript, object, methods

so I'm trying to write a simple game to work with objects and get used to manipulating and working with them. What I want to do is set base stats (user/programmer defined) and then use those base stats in a method to create a complex stat. sample code for what I'm trying to do:

```
var main = function() {
   function Boss (name, lvl, str, dex, int) {
      this.bName = name
      this.level = lvl
      this.strength = str
      this.dexterity = dex
      this.intelligence = int
      this.pAttack  = pAttack();
    }
     function pAttack() {
       (2*this.level) + (2*this.strength);
     }
      var a1Boss = new Boss("test", 50, 500, 500, 500)
      console.log(a1Boss.pAttack)
    }
```

This returns undefined to the console, although everything else returns correctly. Should the pAttack function be set up as 
`var pAttack = function() {code}`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't return a value, so `undefined` is to be expected.

Comment: should there be a `return pAttack` line at the end of the pAttack function?

Comment: Only if you want one, but I can't see a good reason to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of syntax errors.

```
function Boss (name, lvl, str, dex, int) {
    this.bName = name;
    this.level = lvl;
    this.strength = str;
    this.dexterity = dex;
    this.intelligence = int;
    this.pAttack  = this.pAttack();
}
Boss.prototype = {
    pAttack: function () {
        return (2*this.level) + (2*this.strength); 
    },
    pDefend: function () {
        //Defend stuff
    },
    levelUp: function () {
        this.level = this.level + 1;
    }
};

var a1Boss = new Boss("test", 50, 500, 500, 500);
console.log(a1Boss.pAttack)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLhrek8h/1/

Comment: The code doesn't actually throw a `SyntaxError`, so there aren't any syntax errors. However, there is indeed a lot of poor syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help andybeli, this solution works for me. Sorry for the sloppy formatting on here, I use an IDE while I'm actually coding stuff, so I get a bit sloppy typing it into normal text formatting.

Another question, is it possible to assign multiple functions as prototypes within the same bracket? something like:

      `Obj.prototype = {
            var1: function () {...}
            var2: function () {...}
            var3: function () {...}
        }`

Comment: Yes you can. I just edit the answer with some examples. Don't forget the commas after each one, except on the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. One last question before I have to actually get back to work. On the levelUp function, would that just be called from another function (triggered event when xp reaches nextLevel) like `if (a1Boss.currentExp >= nextLevel) {  return a1Boss.levelUp(); }`

Comment: Yes that would be good alternative. Can you vote up my answer too please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your method to be attached to the new object do this :

```
this.pAttack = pAttack;
// and the function should be initialized as a variable
var pAttack = function(){...};
```

If you want your method to be attached to the prototype :

```
Boss.prototype.pAttack = pAttack;
```

Comment: So, here's what I changed it to:

`var pAttack = function () {
      return (2*this.lvl) + (2*this.str);
    }`

Which now logs "function main/pAttack()" to the console

Answer (score 0):

Currently `pAttack` is not invoked in the context of a `Boss` instance so `this` is not pointing at what you expect, you have 3 options

In all cases, don't forget to `return` from the `pAttack` function!

---

**Option 1**, Have instances inherit `pAttack`

After defining `pAttack`, add the following

```
Boss.prototype.pAttackFn = pAttack;
```

What does this do?
It makes all instances of `Boss`, i.e. *Objects* constructed by `new Boss`, inherit the function `pAttack` as the property `pAttackFn` so you can call it e.g.

```
this.pAttack = this.pAttackFn();
```

---

**Option 2**, Define the context of invocation using `.call` or `.apply`

```
this.pAttack  = pAttack.call(this);
```

---

**Option 3**, Give `pAttack` parameters instead of relying on `this`

```
function pAttack(lvl, str) {
    return (2 * lvl) + (2 * str);
}
```

Then

```
this.pAttack  = pAttack(this.level, this.strength);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return a value. I would create it as a method of the object, however, and call it as such:

```
var main = function() {
    function Boss(name, lvl, str, dex, int) {
        this.bName = name;
        this.level = lvl;
        this.strength = str;
        this.dexterity = dex;
        this.intelligence = int;
        this.pAttack = function() {
            return (2 * this.level) + (2 * this.strength);
        }
    }
    var a1Boss = new Boss("test", 50, 500, 500, 500);
    console.log(a1Boss.pAttack());
};

main(); // outputs '1100' to the console
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. I'm going to use the other method provided for me on this page to set up the pAttack function as a prototype of the Boss class as I will have multiple bosses and it will be easier to read to have all the equations for calculating attack/defense/ect in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

You've actually executed the method `pAttack` instead of assigning it. Since `pAttack` returns nothing, `undefined` is returned as an alternative.

So just don't execute it,

```
this.pAttack  = pAttack;
```

or return something

```
function pAttack() {
    return (2*this.level) + (2*this.strength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that may help out depending on what you're doing in the long run is passing in arguments into your function, and returning that value.

```
function pAttack(level, strength) {
   return (2*level) + (2*strength);
}
```

and calling it with

```
this.pAttack = pAttack(this.level, this.strength);
```